# Encountering an error in docker: unknown shorthand flag: 'd' in -d when entering command docker-compose up -d

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When using a new docker container, at first the commands work but after a day of not using my computer the commands stopped working because of the error:

> Encountering an error in docker: unknown shorthand flag: 'd' in -d when entering command docker-compose up -d

Even when the docker container is active it still encounters this error. On the fresh docker installation all the following commands work:

```
docker-compose up -d
docker-compose restart web
docker-compose logs -f --tail=10 web
```

Comment: what command exactly produces the error and in what situation? I don't quite get it from your question

Comment: @Matthias When I enter any docker commands it shows an error like this for example I enter the command docker-compose up -d it shows this "error unknown shorthand flag: 'd' in -d". Thank you sir for your time answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you put the `-d` *after* the `up` command:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Verify options for your install of `docker-compose`:

```
docker-compose --version
docker compose up --help
```